# access get top and last rows

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

let's say I have a table CData with the columns CName, Amount1, Amount2.
Now I want to use a query to get calculate the difference between Amount1 and Amount2 for each distinct CName and, as a result of the query, get the ~1000 rows with the biggest difference and the 1000~ rows with the smallest (or most negative) difference. It doesn't matter if the results come in one table or two.

1) I am aware of the function TOP and so I could do this with two queries and sort by Difference (once ascending, once descending). Is there a way to do this in one query, though? This would save some time.

2) General question: When I define a field in my query (in this example "Difference"), can I somehow use it to, for example, sort the data by it? Like this (well, it's not working, but to give you an idea of what I mean):

```
SELECT CData.CName, CData.Amount2-CData.Amount1 AS Difference
FROM CData
GROUP BY CData.CName
ORDER BY Difference
```

Or do I always have to do the following:

```
...
 ORDER BY CData.Amount2-CData.Amount1
```

Not much of a difference in this example, I just wanted to know if that's possible in general.

Comment: Off the bat, #2 - No. You cannot use the alias like that, you need to put the expression in the `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 0):

which aggregate functino do you want to perform for your differences?  Avg?  Sum?

```
SELECT CName, avg(Amount2-Amount1) AS Difference
FROM CData
GROUP BY CName
```

btw, to do it in 'one' query, you could use a union query on two subqueries, one with the TOP 1000 asc, one with the TOP 1000 desc

looks like Access is not allowing you to use an alias in the `ORDER BY` Clause, if you use the QBE grid you can change the format from the UI to SQL and it repeats the calculation in the `ORDER BY`clause.

---

Hi, John.
Check out [the SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for instructions on how to use options such as formatting code.

Not sure if this will work for you, but you can try something like:

```
select * from
(SELECT TOP 3 
CName, Date_Sale, Sum(Amount) AS SumA, 99999-Sum(Amount) as srt
FROM 
Data 
GROUP BY 
CName, Date_Sale 

UNION 

SELECT TOP 3 
CName, Date_Sale, Sum(Amount) AS SumA, Sum(Amount) as srt
FROM 
Data 
GROUP BY 
CName, Date_Sale) u
order by
srt
```

Comment: First off, how do I format my example as code? 
Secondly, thanks for the answer. I've tried it now on a sample database with the columns CName, Date_Sale, Amount.

SELECT TOP 3 CData.CName, Data.Date_Sale, Sum(Amount) AS SumA
FROM Data
GROUP BY Data.CName, Data.Date_Sale
ORDER BY Sum(Amount) DESC

UNION  

SELECT  TOP 3 Data.CName, Data.Date_Sale, Sum(Amount) AS SumA
FROM Data
GROUP BY Data.CName, Data.Date_Sale
ORDER BY Sum(Amount);


It gives me an error due to the ORDER BY statement: "The order by expression includes fields that are not selected by the query". How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Sort the first time ASC (Ascending) and the second time DESC (Descending)

```
SELECT TOP 1000 
    CData.CName, 
    CData.Amount2 - CData.Amount1 AS Difference
FROM CData
GROUP BY CData.CName
ORDER BY CData.Amount2 - CData.Amount1 ASC

SELECT TOP 1000 
    CData.CName, 
    CData.Amount2 - CData.Amount1 AS Difference
FROM CData
GROUP BY CData.CName
ORDER BY CData.Amount2 - CData.Amount1 DESC
```